# How to optimize python code in pure pythonic way without cythonizing it

Tags: python, optimization, cython

### Edited:

*(This post has been largely edited compared to its previous version).*

For test purpose I have a module, say, `ptest.py` :

```py
# ptest.py
def testfunc(*args) :
    # Some process that can take significant time. There may be some integers larger than 2^64.
```

After cythonizing it to, say, `ctest.pyx` I got an increase in performance with some further tests (as expected).

Now for some integer value large enough the program may throw `OverflowError` while in pure python that might not happen. In this case, can I raise `SomeError` with information (say, `ValueError('The number should not be greater than some value')`) in cython as we do in python ?

Even I did the same,

```py
if n > 2**64:
    raise ValueError("Number should be a non negative integer less than 2^64.")
```

it kept showing: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C unsigned long`. Seems to ignore the condition completely.

So, how can I inform the user ? And finally, can I use cython in pure python without cythonizing the entire program (that is without setup, build etc.) as I don't want to lose those functionality of python (in this case raising Exception, handling sufficiently large integer etc.)?

I tried other methods from `cython` module (following `Cython` doc.) like, `cython.declare`, `cython.exceptval` etc. in `.py` file but they all seem to be a failure in improving the performance. I haven't approached `ctypes` yet as I want the proper technique beforehand.

Comment: To be clear: is this a question about optimizing that specific function `testfunc`, or a more general question?

Comment: @Passerby This question is absolutely in general sense. I designed that function `testfunc` deliberately to delay the overall process and thus being able to distinguish between the approaches.

Comment: Introducing a delay by consuming CPU time is rarely a good idea

Comment: How does "I designed that function `testfunc` deliberately to delay the overall process" fit with wanting a faster `testfunc`? You have incompatible goals here

Comment: There is no generic magic bullet when it comes to optimization. Here you build a list by adding one element at a time: the optimized way is to use a list comprehension. But it really depend on the original code...

Comment: a) `ctypes` is to do with linking external C code. It has nothing to do with performance and won't help you. b) Cython can handle exceptions perfectly well so your second point is nonsense. c) If there was a magical way to retain all the flexibility of Python but to get better performance then everyone would be using it already (PyPy's pretty good though, but has trade-offs). Cython gets better performance by restricting things. Since you aren't prepared to do that you're stuck I think

Comment: This specific operation can be written as `list(range(n,-1,-1))` or `list(range(n+1)[::-1])`.

Comment: Those features that make python 'ideal' cost run time.  `numpy.arange(n,-1,-1)` is faster than the list/range, but doesn't handle bignums - though for  large enough `n` both will hit memory limits.

Comment: I think it's best to use `cython` just for the tasks that take the longest, and benefit most from it's rewrite.  Instead of cythonizing the whole program, identify the critical functions.  It's common in `numpy` and `scipy` to have functions that check inputs, and then pass the task to compiled code for selected case, and using slower code for cases that can't be handled that way.

Answer (score 1):

I timed and ran the OP's code with a value of n==1_000 10_000 times. The duration was ~0.77s

Changing the code to use a list comprehension as follows:

```
def testfunc(n: int) -> list :
    return [n_ for n_ in range(n, 0, -1)]
```

...reduced the duration to ~0.26s

Comment: Please, have a look at the updated comment.

Comment: Your question states "Nonetheless, I want the performance improvement in pure pythonic way...". That is exactly what my Answer gives you

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you're asking is to program better. In this example you can just do:

```
list(range(n,0,-1))
```

And that's the thing here: by thinking about what you want to do you can do the same thing smarter and clearer. That's what it means to work in a pythonic way.

Other things you can do to optimize code pythonically:

- think of smarter algorithms (with pen and paper)
- vectorize (use numpy) whenever you can
- use the right type, if you want to check if an item is in a list, a set might be more appropriate
- don't index lists (this is relatively slow), you can usually iterate over them
- there's usually a library that does what you want faster than you can program it (often written in C)

Comment: Agreed. But for example, I write a program in `python` and in `C` using same algorithm, however almost everytime c outperforms python when speed matters most. Again in case of number (of type int, which is another reason for asking this question) related case c may throw overflow error while python can handle it easily (upto certain extent though). Now how can I do (actually, I have no idea) something in Cython like `raise ValueError(Number should be less than some value)` ?

Comment: I have heard python programs can be run with significantly high performance using cython, but should not I sacrifice some features (as mentioned earlier) of python as well ? So is it possible, keeping all the features of python raise its performance to c's level using cython ?

Comment: "Now how can I do (actually, I have no idea) something in Cython like `raise ValueError(Number should be less than some value)`" Cython can handle almost all valid Python code! Have you tried `raise ValueError("Number should be less...")`? Why not try it _before_ asking here?

Comment: Yes I did like, `if n > 2**64: raise ValueError("Number should be a non negative integer less than 2^64.")` but it seemed to be ignored as it raised `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C unsigned long`.

Comment: I think what's happening is that the `OverflowError` is raised earlier (when your Cython function is called) and therefore always happens before your custom error. You should delay converting the argument to C `int` until you've done your check (i.e. leave the argument `n` as an untyped value, and then assign it to a typed C value after the check)

Comment: Actually I want the user to provide any large integer (as, python can handle sufficiently large integer, beyond 64-bit) so that I don't even have to set Error messages. I know with sufficiently large value performance may decreases, that's why I was looking for a pure pythonic approach but with a performance of a low level language like c/ c++.